# Не удаляется файл. Как понять по какой причине?

Tags: java, файловая-система

Есть код:

```
File f =new File("myfolder"+File.separator+"myfile.temp");

if(!f.delete()){System.out.println("NOT DELETE " +f);}
```

Файл не удаляется. Вызывается в конце программы, по идее файл никто уже не держит. Пробовал через try-catch, но исключение не генерирует. Как можно узнать почему не удаляется файл?

Comment: Для начала войти отладчиком внутрь метода `delete()` и узнать в каком месте конкретно возвращается `false`.

Comment: проверьте корректность пути, мне кажется он неверен.

Comment: Внутри метода delete()  security и isInvalid проходит. Т.е дело в там. Путь точный получаю через f.getAbsolutePath(). В чём проблема вообще не пойму.

Comment: Может можно как-то вызвать системное исключение?

Comment: пробуй  FileUtils.forceDelete(f) чтобы словить исключение

Comment: или посмотри кем файл занят

Comment: Файл точно присутсвует по пути `f.getAbsolutePath()`?

Comment: Смотрю вот так: if(f.exists())
          {System.out.println("Файл существует " +f.getAbsolutePath());
          if(!f.delete()){System.out.println("NOT DELETE " +f.getAbsolutePath());}}
          else {System.out.println("Файл не найден " +f.getAbsolutePath());}   
И файл существует. Видит его. Но не удаляет.

Comment: @ Senior Automator , что подключать что бы увидеть FileUtils?

Comment: В общем пошёл я другим путем и получил таки ошибку: Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом. Теперь понятно почему не удалялся. Буду разбираться почему и кто не освободил. Всем спасибо.